# How do you manually add libraries to HTML projects in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

When I first create am HTML Project in Netbeans, it propmts me with an option to add libraries to the project.  My question is, what are the steps to manually add one of the listed libraries **after** you've already created the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click your project name in the `Projects` tab.

Click `Properties`

In the `Categories` pane select `Libraries`

And then you can add 3 types of Libraries (Project, Library, Jar/Folder)